# Trimming text in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

How to get following result in ASP.NET:

INPUT string: `"Duck, Donald"`

Required String: `"Donald Duck"`

P.S: The input string is dynamic.

Comment: Is there some sort of 'pattern' that you know up front? Or do you use some list to lookup possible strings? Or is the question more about that when someone puts in `something, somethingelse` that it should always become `somethingelse something`?

Comment: Yes. The input is coming from a list. The format which i receive is "Last name, First name" and the output of my next page which i want to display is "First name last name"

The input is always in this same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that takes the comma separated name as input, splits it and returns the new, rearranged name as output.

```
Public Function CreateName(ByVal name as String) as String

  Dim values() as String = name.Split(",")
  Dim newName as String = String.Empty

  If values.length > 1 Then
    newName = values(1).Trim() & " " & values(0).Trim()
  Else
    newName = values(0).Trim()
  End If

  Return newName

End Sub


.
.
.

Dim rearranged as String = CreateName("Duck, Donald")
```

Comment: @riygbiv: This one is perfect :) ... Thnx!

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim name As String = "Duck, Donald"
        If name.Contains(",") Then
            Dim fullname As Array = Split(name.ToString, ",")
            Dim final As String = fullname(1).trim() + " " + fullname(0).trim()
        End If
```

Comment: highlight your example in the editor and click the little 101010 button to format it as code. also you should probably call `.Trim()` on each array item.

Comment: @Johnny, Thanks. The suggestion looks good. Can you suggest me an additional 'if' condition to identify if there is any Comma in string, then only to reverse/split these strings. Probably can be exceptional condition.

Comment: Just use, an "if name.contains(",") then" statement

Comment: Dim name As String = "Duck, Donald"
        If name.Contains(",") Then
            Dim fullname As Array = Split(name.ToString, ",")
            Dim final As String = fullname(1).trim() + " " + fullname(0).trim()
        End If

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the code yourself to split by the , using the string's split method, and reverse them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There's a million ways to skin a cat, but how about using Linq?

```
using System.Linq;

string input = "Duck, Donald";
string output = string.Concat(input.Split(',').Select(x => (" " + x)).Reverse()).Trim();
```

I'm sure someone will come up with an easier way!

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help. But is the code for C# ? I have asp.net with VB and framework 1.1

Comment: @RMN, are you using framework 1.1? Why oh why? Save yourself a lot of trouble and get a newer version

Comment: i would definately love to do that, if that was in my hands :( Unfortunately i have no options other than solving this in 1.1 :)